# gtag not pulling URL in label

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, gtag.js

I'm trying to pull the URL dynamically as a label when an event is triggered. I've set the gtag like as below:

```
gtag('event', 'Lead generation', {
  'event_category': 'ACT',
  'event_label': **url**
});
```

Comment: Might consider adding a bit more details/effort into your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the URL :

```
gtag('event', 'Lead generation', {
  'event_category': 'ACT',
  'event_label': document.location.href
});
```

But in terms of GA, this is a bad approach. You can always add secondary dimension `page`, to know the URL where it was fired ;)